# hibernate Autoincrement not set in the database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, mariadb

I know that this question has been asked many times but the answers are not perfect.

I would like to set a primary key column with Auto-Increment. Once I create the database, the column is there but AI is not set.

This is a sample code for auto increment

```
public class ProjectEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The other problem, is the columns ordering in the database are not the same as the POJO class.

class book{
int ISBN;
String title;
String Author;
String Lang;
int nbPages;
}

In the database, I get: ISBN, LANG, Author, title

Comment: What dialect class are you using, when you generate the database? Also what version of Hibernate are you talking about?

Comment: Your POJO class seems to be named "Book" and have 5 fields, but the code in your question suggests "ProjectEntity" which has 2 columns. Are we looking at the class that's mapped to the table? Please edit your question to clarify. If you are asking 2 separate questions, please delete one of them.

Comment: the POJO class is just an example